# Formatted html text in word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a web application and they asked me to provide a text editor with basic functions (bold, italic, color,...) so they can fill out a small text. This text should be saved in the database and a service has to create a word document out of it with the formatted text in it.
Is it possible to get the formatted text, which is in html, and get it with the correct style/format in a Word document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from HTML <figure> and <figcaption> to Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029282/from-html-figure-and-figcaption-to-microsoft-word)

Answer (score 1):

You can find Rich Text Editor,like http://simditor.tower.im/

Comment: ok, but can I put the styled code I get from the editor into my word document so it shows the same styling?

Comment: yes,You need to import the CSS displayed at the front desk

Comment: Could you explain more please?