# HTML code assign to a Javascript DOM Object

Tags: javascript, php, dom

My ultimate goal is to create a Word DOCX file from a generated HTML page. To do this, I used information from the question here [from HTML <figure> and <figcaption> to Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029282/from-html-figure-and-figcaption-to-microsoft-word) in which one of the answers mentioned a JavaScript plugin that would convert HTML to DOCX ([jquery plugin by Mark Windsoll](https://github.com/markswindoll/jQuery-Word-Export) which converts HTML to Word).

The example in that answer and the plugin was used as a basis for the following code segment. In my program, I have previously created an HTML page (in a WordPress loop) (not just elements of the page, but an entire properly formatted HTML page) that contains the content I want to convert to DOCX. Also, I have loaded the needed JS and CSS needed by the "HTML to Word plugin".

The intent is to take the created HTML (`$post_output`) and use the `wordExport()` function (the JS that converts HTML to DOCX) to create the DOCX file, which I will then save.

```
<?php 
    $x = $post_output ;  // $post_output contains an HTML page with doctype/head/body/etc that was generated by the loop
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false); // supress errors
    $dom->loadHTML($x, LIBXML_NOERROR); // supress errors
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
         $dom.wordExport();
</script>
```

The error I am getting is that the `$dom` object in the script is not available, so the `wordExport()` function is not called.

So I need a way to load the entire HTML string (`$x`) into a JavaScript DOM object so that the `wordExport()` function (which is the HTML to DOCX converter) will work. **(added)** the HTML 'string' is not a page in the browser, it's a generated 'HTML page source' assigned to a PHP string variable.)

**Added**
The HTML string needs to be processed by the Word-to-DOCX jQuery plugin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the fact that both JS and PHP have implementations of the DOM API; that doesn't mean that creating a PHP object will be any use to you for running a JS method. Remember that the JS runs in the browser, after all the PHP has finished, and all it sees is the output you've sent to the browser.

So what you need to do is `echo` that entire string of HTML, so you can pick it up in the JS code. You could make it into a JS string (basically, surround it with `'` marks, but using `json_encode` is a handy way of escaping any quotes etc in the content); or you could echo it as hidden content on the page. Then run it through `jQuery()` to get an appropriate object, and use your library.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, the script that I need to run against the DOM object (created by the PHP code) is a jQuery script (the Word-to-Doc script). So, I need to get the PHP-created DOM object to be processed by that jQuery script. So, not really a client-side thing that needs to process the HTML string. I think.

Comment: @RickHellewell Unless you're running JS on the server, it's definitely a client-side thing. It's certainly got nothing to do with a PHP DOM object. In fact, you don't even want a DOM object once you do get to the JS, you want a jQuery object, so it's best to just forget the DOM ever existed.

Comment: @RickHellewell No. The PHP script runs, it produces some output, which is text, and sends it to the browser; the browser reads that text, and runs some JavaScript, including libraries like jQuery. The browser never sees the PHP code, and the PHP code never sees the browser. If you want the browser to see some HTML, you just send the text of that HTML to the browser, and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you don't want to send the HTML to the browser, but do something with it entirely on the server, then jQuery is the wrong tool for the job. In the case, there are PHP libraries for producing Word documents that you could use instead.

Comment: The HTML doesn't need to go to the browser, it is being built to 'feed' to the HTML to DOCX library to create a DOCX file, which will be saved to the local drive. I had the confusion of forgetting (again) that JS is locally executed, where I need to do all the processing of the HTML code and DOCX conversion as part of the server process. My process creates the HTML code properly but am having problems feeding that to to DOCX converter. And I prefer a free DOCX converter, so still trying to figure that out.Thanks.